# How to fix the error "_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm."

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis

I am trying to get the overlapping features between two layers in a loop. This works fine in most cases but raises an exception in some cases. The exception traceback does not even give any hint what the exception is about.

Code:

```
                    feature1_layers_list = []
                    feature2_layers_list = []

                    layer1 = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'Layer1', 'memory')
                    prov = layer1.dataProvider()
                    prov.addAttributes([QgsField("flash_feat_id", QVariant.Int)])
                    prov.addAttributes([QgsField("lane_type", QVariant.String)])
                    prov.addAttributes([QgsField("center_line_Id", QVariant.String)])
                    layer1.updateFields()

                    for feature1_centerline in feature1_all_center_lines:
                        feature1_Lane_Polygon, lanetype1, center_line_id1 = self.get_lane_border(feature1_centerline,
                                                                                          self.laneCenterline_layer,
                                                                                          centerlineFeatures,
                                                                                          laneBorder_layer,
                                                                                          laneBorderFeatures)

                        if feature1_Lane_Polygon != 0 and lanetype1 != 0:
                            fet = QgsFeature()
                            fields = layer1.fields()
                            fet.setFields(fields, True)
                            fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(feature1_Lane_Polygon.wkt))
                            fet['flash_feat_id'] = int(center_line_id1)
                            fet['lane_type'] = str(lanetype1)
                            fet['center_line_Id'] = str(feature1_centerline)
                            feature1_layers_list.append(fet)

                    prov.addFeatures(feature1_layers_list)
                    layer1.updateExtents()

                    layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:4326', 'Layer2', 'memory')
                    prov2 = layer2.dataProvider()
                    prov2.addAttributes([QgsField("flash_feat_id", QVariant.Int)])
                    prov2.addAttributes([QgsField("lane_type", QVariant.String)])
                    prov2.addAttributes([QgsField("center_line_Id", QVariant.String)])
                    layer2.updateFields()

                    # _writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer1,
                    #                                                    r"C:/QGIS_ShapeFile/output/layer1.shp",
                    #                                                   "utf-8", driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
                    # _writer2 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer2,
                    #                                                   r"C:/QGIS_ShapeFile/output/layer2.shp",
                    #                                                   "utf-8", driverName="ESRI Shapefile")

                    for feature2_centerline in feature2_all_center_lines:
                        feature2_Lane_Polygon, lanetype2, center_line_id2 = self.get_lane_border(feature2_centerline,
                                                                                          self.laneCenterline_layer,
                                                                                          centerlineFeatures,
                                                                                          laneBorder_layer,
                                                                                          laneBorderFeatures)
                        if feature2_Lane_Polygon != 0 and lanetype2 != 0:
                            feat = QgsFeature()
                            fields2 = layer2.fields()
                            feat.setFields(fields2, True)
                            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(feature2_Lane_Polygon.wkt))
                            feat['flash_feat_id'] = int(center_line_id2)
                            feat['lane_type'] = str(lanetype2)
                            feat['center_line_Id'] = str(feature2_centerline)
                            feature2_layers_list.append(feat)

                    prov2.addFeatures(feature2_layers_list)
                    layer2.updateExtents()

                    uuid1 = uuid.uuid4()
                    uuid2 = uuid.uuid4()
                    layer3_path = 'C:/QGIS_ShapeFile/output/layers/layer_' + str(uuid1) + '.shp'
                    layer4_path = 'C:/QGIS_ShapeFile/output/layers/layer_' + str(uuid2) + '.shp'

                    try:
                        algorithmOutput1 = processing.run(
                            "qgis:extractbylocation",
                            {
                                'INPUT': layer1,
                                'INTERSECT': layer2,
                                'OUTPUT': layer3_path,
                                'PREDICATE': [5]
                            }
                        )
                        algorithmOutput2 = processing.run(
                            "qgis:extractbylocation",
                            {
                                'INPUT': layer2,
                                'INTERSECT': layer1,
                                'OUTPUT': layer4_path,
                                'PREDICATE': [5]
                            }
                        )

                        layer3 = QgsVectorLayer(layer3_path, "layer3", "ogr")
                        layer4 = QgsVectorLayer(layer4_path, "layer4", "ogr")
                        self.get_overlap_pair(layer3, layer4)

                    except Exception as e:
                        traceback.print_exc()
```

And below is the stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/sn43673/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ad_qgis\shapefile_validator.py",
>   line 440, in errorInShapeFile
>       'PREDICATE': [5]   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
>   line 105, in run
>       return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
>   line 183, in runAlgorithm
>       raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to the invalid geometry of features in the layers layer1 and layer2. I validated all the geometry of the features and came to know that. The algorithm works fine now.

Comment: Are you able to share your code for validating all features in a geometry? Better yet, is there a Pythonic way to set your QgsProject.instance() to have its Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option, as you would if using QGIS 3.x directly?

I'm scouring the QgsProcessing and  QgsProject classes but don't see any means of ignoring invalid input features..